# Copy dialogue freezes at 0 seconds forever when copying to a USB flash drive

Tags: files

Copy dialogue freezes at 0 seconds forever and I end up with a corrupt file for files bigger than 1GB on a Dell Inspiron N4050 laptop (i3 with 4GB of RAM). The copying goes too fast at the beginning than it hangs at the very end like forever.

FYI:

- when copying from one directory or partition to another or when copying files smaller than 1GB, the copying goes normally.
- The issue persists even if I format or change the USB drive.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you copy the files using the `cp` command? Try copying it with `cp -v path/to/your/file /destination/directory/`. The -v switch gives additional information. If an error or warning is shown, add it to your question.

Comment: I had this problem once - reformatting usb stick to NTFS (in slow mode) helped.

Comment: I am still facing this problem. Any solutions yet? I think, this problem is either exists with linux kernel itself or it is part of gnome. I have experienced this problem with Ubuntu, LinuxMint and Fedora as well.

And all were 64 bit. Linux Kernel and Gnome are the common elements in all these cases.

Comment: how is the USB formated? FAT16 has a file size limit of 1GB.

Answer (score 1):

So for me it was a simple question of waiting, letting it hang on '0 seconds left' until it eventually finished and changed to 'copied'. Looks like the file manager indicator can get pretty inaccurate and the whole workings were also explained at [Gnome, nautilus copy files to USB stops at 100% or near](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/180818).

Answer (score 0):

That's a biggish file, so do you have enough spare RAM left? Tried closing some applications to free up some RAM? Is your hard disc getting full? Emptied rubbish bin recently? What happens with a smaller file: 500MB, 250MB, 125MB in size? I.e. is the problem file-size related?

Comment: Yes I have enough RAM left and the I still can copy smaller files with no issues at all. I still can copy on Windows with no issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

it is a bug in many linux distros.I was using Linux Mint before now Ubuntu i have kept experiencing the same problem.But what you can do is to wait for sometime it will finish
The other solution is below.i tried it and it worked very well

http://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/